# parentNode is undefined for tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

When it reaches the line `this.parentNode.removeChild(this);`

I get the error

> this.parentNode is undefined

In the debugger I pause at the beginning of that statement and see that "this" is: `Object[ tr#CMD01.selected ]` which is exactly what I expect. How is parentNode undefined? I have done a lot of searching for similar problems here and keep finding cases where "this" is not correct, but in my case it is verified by the debugger.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.fn.deleteThisRow = function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
     };
    });
    
    function deleteRow() {
     $("#theList tr.selected").deleteThisRow();
    }
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow
 }
```

```html
    <body>
     <center id='bg'>
     <table id="cmdList"> 
      <thead>
       <tr id="hdrow">
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="theList">
       <tr id="CMD00">
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="CMD01" class="selected">
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="CMD02">
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table> 
 <table id="buttons">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <button onclick='deleteRow()'>Delete</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </center>
    </body>
```

Comment: `this.remove()` will work - see jfriend00's answer for why your code fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement a jQuery method, the value of `this` when it is called will be the jQuery object, not the DOM object.  So, `this.parentNode` does not exist because a jQuery object does not have a property by that name.

You can either use jQuery's `.parent()` or you can get the actual DOM node and then use `.parentNode` on that.

If you only intend on ever processing a single DOM object at a time, you can do this:

```
$.fn.deleteThisRow = function() {
    this[0].parentNode.removeChild(this[0]);
};
```

If your jQuery object may have multiple objects in it, then you can do this:

```
$.fn.deleteThisRow = function() {
    this.remove();
};
```

---

Or, as you may notice, you don't even need a custom method for this.  If you have a jQuery object for the row, you can just call `.remove()` on it directly.

```
function deleteRow() {
    $("#theList tr.selected").remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Getting rid of the custom method is the simplest and does exactly what I want.